# Will a mailbox user know their mailbox has litigation hold?

Tags: permissions, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

Environment:  Office 365 online. Version 15.1.933.16 (2016 CU4?)

We intend on placing a litigation hold on a users mailbox. Prior to placing the hold, I'd like to check if there is any way the user will find out the hold is is in effect. The intent is for them to use their mailbox as usual, but with an indefinite retention strategy.

They are an ordinary user with no special permissions. Cannot use Power-Shell, no access to admin tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Litigation hold and In-place hold are transparent to the user, so they will not know they are on hold.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637980(v=exchg.160).aspx